# Android Studio Camera2 preview screen cannot add UI

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, layout, android-camera2

Android Studio Camera2 preview screen cannot add UI.
I wonder if I can add other UI to the camera preview screen? (Title Bar, Button, Text, etc.)
I tried to add the above UI elements in the XML settings, but still no response during execution.

**The following is my *activity_main.xml* code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="657dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The following is my *fragment_camera.xml* code:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".CameraFragment">

    <com.lightweh.camera2preview.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/textureView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout >
```

**Other codes can refer to:** https://github.com/xGonZh10n/Camera2Preview

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error? Can you show us error logs? Check your permission in Android manifest. Maybe you missing this line.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

I have a suggestion for you. Camera2API is easier than other custom libs to integrate.
Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera

Comment: Hi @Kai Pham

This project did not produce any errors; it was only after the .xml was edited and modified (adding buttons or text), and nothing happens.

In the project, Camera2preview> manifests> AndroidManifest.xml has been added:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`